# cant put if statement in loop C++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I have an assignment for school, very simple, just ordering burgers from a joint and calculating the costs. I've tried to use an if statement to make sure the user likes their order, but it keeps giving me and error, whether my variable "yesorno" is a string or a char.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char yesorno;
int burgers, fries, drinks;
int i=0;
while (i=0) {
    cout<<"Aidan: 'Welcome to the Christopher Burger Joint!\nOur burgers are $4.00, fries are $2.50, and drinks are $1.50.";

    cout<<"\nHow many burgers will you be having today?";
    cin>>burgers;
    cout<<"\nHow many fries will you be having today?";
    cin>>fries;
    cout<<"\nand how many drinks for you today?";
    cin>>drinks;
    cout<<"\nSo here is your current order:\nBurgers: "<<burgers<<"\nFries: "<<fries<<"\nDrinks: "<<drinks;
    cout<<"Is this all?\nYes or No: ";
    cin>>yesorno;
    if (yesorno = "yes") {
        i=2;
    }

}
int grosstotal = (burgers*4)+(fries*2.5)+(drinks*1.5);
int tax = grosstotal*.12;
int total = tax+grosstotal;
cout<<"\nYour total before tax is $"<<grosstotal<<",\nYour tax is $"<<tax<<",\nAnd your total today is $"<<total<<".\nEnjoy!'";


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning yesorno to "yes", not actually checking if it is equal to anything.  That may not be your only problem, but `==` checks for equality, `=` is assignment.

Comment: Compiling without warnings strikes again.

Comment: @chris I added the second equal sign, but now it gives me a new error corresponding to the if statement again "error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string yesorno;
    int burgers, fries, drinks;
    int i=0;
    while (i==0) {
        cout<<"Aidan: 'Welcome to the Christopher Burger Joint!\nOur burgers are $4.00, fries are $2.50, and drinks are $1.50.";

        cout<<"\nHow many burgers will you be having today?";
        cin>>burgers;
        cout<<"\nHow many fries will you be having today?";
        cin>>fries;
        cout<<"\nand how many drinks for you today?";
        cin>>drinks;
        cout<<"\nSo here is your current order:\nBurgers: "<<burgers<<"\nFries: "<<fries<<"\nDrinks: "<<drinks;
        cout<<"Is this all?\nYes or No: ";
        cin>>yesorno;
        if (yesorno == "yes") {
            i=2;
        }

    }
    int grosstotal = (burgers*4)+(fries*2.5)+(drinks*1.5);
    int tax = grosstotal*.12;
    int total = tax+grosstotal;
    cout<<"\nYour total before tax is $"<<grosstotal<<",\nYour tax is $"<<tax<<",\nAnd your total today is $"<<total<<".\nEnjoy!'";


     return 0;
}
```

This works for me.  You were missing a couple of `==`.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong in the original code and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For starters there is assignment instead of comparison in this while statement

```
while (i=0) {
       ^^^
```

In this if statement

```
if (yesorno = "yes") {
           ^^^
```

there is again assignment instead of comparison.

To accept from the user a string like this `"yes"` the variable `yesorno` should be declared as having type `std::string`.

Instead of the `while` loop it is better to use a `do-while` loop. For example

```
int main() {
    string yesorno;
    int burgers, fries, drinks;

    do {
        //...

        cin>>yesorno;
    } while ( yesorno != "yes" );
```

Also you may remove the header `<cstdlib>` because neither declaration from the header is used in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are assigning string yes to the variable yesorno which you are doing wrong there = is a assignment operator for comparison use == for comparison so insted

```
  if (yesorno = "yes") {
        i=2;
    }
```

write

```
if (yesorno == "yes") {
    i=2;
}
```

.

Comment: Can you please Justify?

Comment: `"yes"` is a string literal, which decays to a `char*` when used with comparison operator `==`. So you are comparing a character value with a pointer value, which rarely makes sense.